# Generate a random number in docker-compose file?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the following docker-compose file:

```
version: '2'

services:
  puppetagent:
    build: .
    extra_hosts:
      puppet: "${MASTER_IP}"
    image: 2klic/device:v1
    container_name: test_agent
```

I'd like to modify `container_name: test_agent` in a way that appends a random 4 digit number to the name test_agent.

*E.g. test_agent1243, test_agent4352, ect.*

Is there a convenient way to do something like this?

Answer (score 1):

You can substitute the random number by an environment variable , some thing like this https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env-file , so before every scale up you can substitute a random value to the env variable from a script.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just omit `container_name` and let compose allocate names to it?